# Webpack failure while trying to import a custom Angular theme

Tags: webpack, angular-material

The error that shows up when I try to build my app is

> *[webpack][error] Module build failed: Unclosed quote (3805:24)
>
>   // Wrapper element that provides the theme background when the
>
>   // user's content isn't inside of a `mat-sidenav-container`.
>
>                                             ^
>
>      .mat-app-background {
>
>     $background: map-get($theme, background);
>
>     background-color: mat-color($background, background);
>
>      }*

I am using *webpack 1.12.x* and trying to import an *Angular material* custom theme in my `main.scss` file. I was following the steps provided [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-custom-theme).

My *webpack* loader looks something like this:

```
module: {
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loader: 'ts',
  },
  {
    test: /\.json$/,
    loader: 'json',
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
    exclude: [/app/],
  },
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
        exclude: [/app/],
    },
  {
    test: /\.(html|css)$/,
    loader: 'raw',
    include: [/app/],
    exclude: ['index.html'],
  },
  {
    test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot)$/,
    loader: 'url?prefix=font/&limit=5000'
  },
  {
    test: /\.ttf$/,
    loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream',
  },
  {
    test: /\.svg$/,
    loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml',
  },
],
}
```

Comment: Please show the offending code - specifically line 3805.

Comment: That is the offending code ,
// Wrapper element that provides the theme background when the
// user's content isn't inside of a mat-sidenav-container.
.mat-app-background {
  $background: map-get($theme, background);
  background-color: mat-color($background, background);
}
Its in the material design minified file

Comment: Share the file that the offending code is in.

Comment: Its the usual, angular material design code
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/9c075f5c50b4d91ad91d4f7fb180f68c5de45cd4/src/lib/core/_core.scss#L43